# yii2 rbac check for role user->can()

Tags: database, yii2, rbac

i installed and configured rbac in yii2 with DBManager but i don't get the "check" working with:

```
if (Yii::$app->user->can('waitAccess')) {
    echo "yes it is pending.";
} else {
    echo "nothing";
}
```

I made 3 users with my different roles but each of them is able to see the first line despite they don't have the permission. "In my opinion"

This here is my rbacController

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
public function actionInit()
{
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

    // add "user2View" permission
    $user2View = $auth->createPermission('user2View');
    $user2View->description = 'user2 view';
    $auth->add($user2View);

    // add "user1View" permission
    $user1View = $auth->createPermission('user1View');
    $user1View->description = 'user1 view';
    $auth->add($user1View);

    // add "waitAccess" permission
    $waitAccess = $auth->createPermission('waitAccess');
    $waitAccess->description = 'wait for Access';
    $auth->add($waitAccess);

    // add "seeConfig" permission
    $seeConfig = $auth->createPermission('seeConfig');
    $seeConfig->description = 'Access to the administrative Config';
    $auth->add($seeConfig);

    // add "user2" role and give this role the "user2View" permission
    $user2 = $auth->createRole('user2');
    $auth->add($user2);
    $auth->addChild($user2, $user2View);

    // add "user1" role and give this role the "user1View" permission
    $user1 = $auth->createRole('user1');
    $auth->add($user1);
    $auth->addChild($user1, $user1View);

    // add "pending" role and give this role the "waitAccess" permission
    $pending = $auth->createRole('pending');
    $auth->add($pending);
    $auth->addChild($pending, $waitAccess);

    // add "superadmin" role and give this role the "seeConfig" permission
    $superadmin = $auth->createRole('superadmin');
    $auth->add($superadmin);
    $auth->addChild($superadmin, $seeConfig);
    $auth->addChild($superadmin, $user2View);
    $auth->addChild($superadmin, $user1View);
    $auth->addChild($superadmin, $waitAccess);

}
}
```

Maybe anyone have a clue what I can look for.

Update: This is my DB Structure
[image: DB Structure of my yii2 rbac]

Update 2:

**I solved it!
The stupidity didn't took a look on the default rules where all users where written down. So everyone had access. Deleting that line and adding pending for standard it resolved it.**

Comment: Tried different permissions no change. Can anyone approve that my roles and permission file is right?

Comment: there will be a rbac folder inside the frontend or backend folder if you are using advance config. there will be three file in that. check if that exist. If yes what are the names of those files?

Comment: Yes I am using the advanced configuration. And there is no folder called rbac, isn't it because I use "DBManager" instead of "PHPManager" so that everything is stored in the database?

Comment: 'defaultRoles' => ['superadmin', 'councel', 'company', 'pending'], that was the problem!

Comment: is there an extension for yii2 where users and roles can be created and roles can be assigned to a user via web interface ?

Comment: i dont know if this here has an interface for the rbac but it does the rest: https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user

Comment: Yes there is: https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin